# iCarousel (Coverflow) with table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata, icarousel

I got an app with one table. First cell is the coverflow from iCarousel.

When i rotate coverflow and items changed i reload table view:

```
-(void)carouselDidScroll:(iCarousel *)_carousel{
    if (curCategory != _carousel.currentItemIndex)
    {
        curCategory=(int)_carousel.currentItemIndex;
        NSLog(@"%i",curCategory);
        [table reloadData];
    }
}
```

But this code drop finger action of rotating. Because first cell with coverflow reload too.

Can i reload table, but dont touch first cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reload just a range of cells using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:

It might make more sense to make the carousel be the table header view instead of the first cell though.

Comment: yeah! i already do it in this way. But you the only man, how answered this question. So, thnx, and i marked you answer as a write answer =)